# Is Supplemental 20/80 health insurance still available in the US?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance

Are supplemental health insurance plans (those that can pay your out of pocket expenses after some deductible up to the limit that your primary insurance covers) still available in the US?

I was searching for them and maybe my google-fu is weak, but all I could find was major injury, hospital stay and Medicare gap insurance nothing for regular gap insurance.

Comment: I get plenty of results for "supplemental health insurance".

Comment: @DStanley: yes, and there are a lot of hits for gap insurance as well.  And as far as I can tell the first 100 or so results all referr to something different.  If you have a definite link that says otherwise I would like to see it.